# neo4j keeps giving erros and is not running,can you help me with its errors?

Tags: java, windows, neo4j, timeout, startup

I downloaded neo4j.zip from its site and extract it.
I downloaded and installed jdk 7, I have two folders in :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
```

And I clicked on New and made a variable named JAVA_HOME and its value is

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
```

I have added

```
org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout=0
```

line to my  neo4j-server.properties file because of timeout error and
I have changed the port number in  neo4j-server.properties file from 7474 to 80 and 8085, this is my  neo4j-server.properties now:

```
################################################################
# Neo4j
#
# neo4j-server.properties - runtime operational settings
#
################################################################

#***************************************************************
# Server configuration
#***************************************************************

# location of the database directory
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db

# Low-level graph engine tuning file
org.neo4j.server.db.tuning.properties=conf/neo4j.properties

# Database mode
# Allowed values:
# HA - High Availability
# SINGLE - Single mode, default.
# To run in High Availability mode, configure the neo4j.properties config file, then uncomment this line:
#org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA

# Let the webserver only listen on the specified IP. Default is localhost (only
# accept local connections). Uncomment to allow any connection. Please see the
# security section in the neo4j manual before modifying this.
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0

# Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true

#
# HTTP Connector
#

# http port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=8085

#
# HTTPS Connector
#

# Turn https-support on/off
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true

# https port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473

# Certificate location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.cert

# Private key location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.key

# Internally generated keystore (don't try to put your own
# keystore there, it will get deleted when the server starts)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.keystore.location=data/keystore

# Comma separated list of JAX-RS packages containing JAX-RS resources, one
# package name for each mountpoint. The listed package names will be loaded
# under the mountpoints specified. Uncomment this line to mount the
# org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged.HelloWorldResource.java from
# neo4j-server-examples under /examples/unmanaged, resulting in a final URL of
# http://localhost:7474/examples/unmanaged/helloworld/{nodeId}
#org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged


#*****************************************************************
# HTTP logging configuration
#*****************************************************************

# HTTP logging is disabled. HTTP logging can be enabled by setting this
# property to 'true'.
org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=false

# Logging policy file that governs how HTTP log output is presented and
# archived. Note: changing the rollover and retention policy is sensible, but
# changing the output format is less so, since it is configured to use the
# ubiquitous common log format
org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml

#*****************************************************************
# Administration client configuration
#*****************************************************************

# location of the servers round-robin database directory. possible values:
# - absolute path like /var/rrd
# - path relative to the server working directory like data/rrd
# - commented out, will default to the database data directory.
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rrdb.location=data/rrd
org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout=0
```

but again when I run Neo4j.bat by double clicking on it, cmd window will open and java window will open and will close after some seconds and cmd window will close after it and

```
http://localhost:8085/browser/
```

is unavailable.

This is my error from

```
C:\Users\Fereshteh\Desktop\neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0-windows\neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0\data\graph.db\messages

2015-04-10 01:56:42.689+0000 ERROR [o.n.s.e.EnterpriseBootstrapper]: Failed to start Neo Server on port [8085]
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Wanted record LOG_VERSION, but this record wasn't read since the neostore didn't contain it
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:255) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:117) [neo4j-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:69) [neo4j-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Wanted record LOG_VERSION, but this record wasn't read since the neostore didn't contain it
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.record.NeoStoreUtil.getValue(NeoStoreUtil.java:127) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.record.NeoStoreUtil.getLogVersion(NeoStoreUtil.java:150) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recoveryNeededAt(StoreRecoverer.java:57) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:62) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:71) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:387) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:195) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
```

And in my `C:\Users\Fereshteh\Desktop\neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0-windows\neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0\data\log`
I have just README and windows-wrapper.0.0.txt and windows-wrapper.0.0.log.lck

what should I do to be able to run Neo4j and work with it?
I have windows 7 x86
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run it without any of your adjustments, i.e. a vanilla instance, to ascertain if it is an environment issue or your changes?

Comment: Did you use a already existing database? Or a blank directory for data/graph.db ?

Comment: Did you use a previous database? What about access rights to the directory? `C:\Users\Fereshteh\Desktop\neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0-windows\neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0\data\graph.db\messages`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error today. In my case, it was because the files in the database directory were corrupted (I unzipped an existing graph which failed on first try). After I unzipped the existing graph database correctly - and the database files were fine - it worked. So, maybe your database directory is also corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Move the neo4j folder to another directory -> \Program'*thisblankisbad*'Files\ <- was the cause for me. I was trying to reinstall the service on Windows with

```
neo4j install-service
```

and neo4j threw:

```
neo4j Error: mainclass org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jCommand could not be found or loaded cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jCommand
```

after i moved the neo4j folder to another directory (NO BLANKS!!!) it was fine
windows 10, neo4j v4.4.9